# Which type of Android Services should I use?

Tags: android, service

I try to get services into my weather application. 
Let's assume that user has set up locations (cities list), and that he tap an Update button. In my case, this tap is caught by `MainActivity`. After that, the application should read from sqlite user locations to update weather data, loop through this list of locations, for each of them send request to weather provider, parse json and put weather data into database. On success, the current view should be updated to show data that was just received. How should I separate all this logic between `MainActivity` and services, and which type of services should I use? I think, it can be intent service  to get the weather from provider and insert it into database, and bound service to update user layout (view).
Also, when we have a weather update schedule, should be created a service, that runs permanently in the background, and launches weather update process automatically. Which type of android service schould be used in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods.
Just some of them.

1. Bind service and Activity ( imho, the ugliest)
2. Send broadcast intent between activity and service. Lags appear while datea transfer.
3. Send message between of them.
4. And, imho, the most useful way (that doesn't exist is specifications) is to set both Activity and Service as interfaces (listeners) that are stored inside `Application` class.
5. By the way you can send data via both singleton and application class.

Comment: Thanks! The 4th way I want to learn some time. But now I'm interested, which service type are usually used for list of cases: 1. Service which asks a json from api, and puts its data into database; 2. Service which just runs in the background and launches the Service 1 when it's time according to schedule.